# Users cannot log into VM server that is joined to a DC

Tags: windows, rdp, remote, users, desktop

I've been having a problem recently where i have a VM machine that is running windows server 2012 which is connected to a DC running the same OS, on the DC i have ADUC running with all of my users configured and added into the remote desktop users group but for some reason whenever i log into the VM using the DOMAINNAME/user prefix i get the "the connection was denied because the user account is not authorised for remote log-in"

the only way of resolving this is to log into the VM as a admin and using the following command:

"net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" "UserName" /add"

surely creating the user through AD and adding them into the Remote Desktop user group would authenticate them to log into the VM?

Comment: `surely creating the user through AD and adding them into the Remote Desktop user group would authenticate them to log into the VM?` No. It needs to be the local group.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use groups instead of adding many users directly onto the server.

Create a new AD Group.
Add desired users (you can also select 'all authenticated users' to catch everyone) to that group.
Add that new AD group as a member of the local Remote Desktop Users group on the server(s) you want.

If you have numerous servers, you can also make a GPO that adds that AD group to the local Remote Desktop Users group of all member servers.

Answer (score 0):

The `Remote Desktop Users` group *in Active Directory* doesn't actually do anything, it's there only due to a technical reason (*).

In order to RDP into a machine, the user needs to be a member of the *local* `Remote Desktop Users` group on the target machine.

Or, to be more exact, the user needs the `Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services` right, which by default is granted to the `Administrators` and `Remote Desktop Users` *local* groups.

You can use a GPO to either 1) put domain users or groups in the `Remote Desktop Users` local group on multiple machines, or 2) directly grant the `Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services` right to domain users or groups.

And yes, you *can* create a GPO that grants the `Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services` right to the *domain* `Remote Desktop Users` group; that would actually accomplish what you thought to be true by default.

---

(*) The reason is, when you create a domain, all local users and groups on the machine which becomes the first domain controller are transformed into Active Directory users and groups; but this doesn't grant them any actual permission.